# MySQL Select row A and row B if row A exists

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I've got a table with two columns, different types of IDs. If a particular ID (2) is in the second column (widget_id), I want to have a list of all the first column IDs in two cases:

1. When there's also a widget_id of 1 for the same first column ID,
2. When there's no existing widget_id of 1 for the same first column ID.

Currently I have a query which grabs all rows with a widget_id of 1 or 2. How can I focus in on what I need?

My current query:

```
SELECT *
FROM db.table
WHERE (widget_id = 1 OR widget_id = 2)
ORDER BY gadget_id;
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+
|gadget_id |widget_id |
+----------+----------+
|100       |1         |
|101       |1         |
|101       |2         |
|102       |1         |
|103       |2         |
|104       |1         |
|104       |2         |
|105       |2         |
+----------+----------+
```

The output I'm looking for:

Both #1 & #2:

```
+----------+----------+
|gadget_id |widget_id |
+----------+----------+
|101       |1         |
|101       |2         |
|104       |1         |
|104       |2         |
+----------+----------+
```

Only #2:

```
+----------+----------+
|gadget_id |widget_id |
+----------+----------+
|103       |2         |
|105       |2         |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you need to `group by gadget_id`.
For the 1st case the condition is that both 1 and 2 must exist:

```
select * from tablename 
where gadget_id in (
  select gadget_id
  from tablename
  where widget_id in (1, 2)
  group by gadget_id
  having count(distinct widget_id) = 2
)
```

For the 2nd case the condition is that 1 must not exist:

```
select * from tablename 
where gadget_id in (
  select gadget_id
  from tablename
  where widget_id in (1, 2)
  group by gadget_id
  having sum(widget_id = 1) = 0 
)
```

If 1 and 2 are the only values in column `widget_id` you can omit the condition:

```
where widget_id in (1, 2)
```

in both queries.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kHQhzVHrEvKxL6H7xA1mFJ/0).
Results:

**Query #1**

```
| gadget_id | widget_id |
| --------- | --------- |
| 101       | 1         |
| 101       | 2         |
| 104       | 1         |
| 104       | 2         |
```

**Query #2**

```
| gadget_id | widget_id |
| --------- | --------- |
| 103       | 2         |
| 105       | 2         |
```